# Professional tax for employees - startup in India

Tags: india, tax-deduction, small-business, start-up

If I have  online business with one employee who will be working from home, do I need to deduct professional tax as applicable from his salary and submit or I can avoid professional taxes for the employees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tax is depended upon state where you are registered and the salary paid. More [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.charteredclub.com/professional-tax/&ved=0CBwQFjABahUKEwiFnbu7w9jIAhWNA44KHRpzDfk&usg=AFQjCNG3FR_682hno80vLb4M-ma6vqT8Ew&sig2=GJwmFyKdYZyx-oHWPdgNPw)

If you employ contract you need not pay tax.